# What is The Event?

Tags: the-event

In the marketing prior to the start of the airing of the TV series [*The Event*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Event), we are told that the numerous goings-on in the first few episodes are not *The* Event.  Do we know what the event that the show's title refers to is?

Comment: Is this on-topic? Seems too time localized... I'm not voting down since I'm unsure...

Comment: I don't see how it's time-localized.  Something that happened during the show is The event, I don't think it's particularly clear what it is.

Comment: up until the point that it's revealed, it's un-answerable.

Comment: @DVK and yet there are several open Doctor Who questions that are currently un-answerable.  This question is about a show that's completed airing every episode it'll have.

Comment: I was hoping this question would be about [the Quiz Broadcast](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ga_rCnueID8)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Event, as explained in the series finale, is:

> A transformation by Sofia's people into something "better" than what they currently are. Lee explains that Sofia's people were on Earth "first", and they left to prevent the Event from taking place. He implies that by staying on Earth (or coming back), the transcendence will take place. It was not explained why they wanted to prevent this from occurring.

Comment: Good call, I had totally forgot that they did specifically mention that in the finale.

Comment: I'm pretty certain the reason they wanted to prevent it was explained:   The Event would be so catastrophic, nothing else would survive.